# How to align branches

Tags: mercurial

I am  using Mercurial version 5.0.2.

On one server I pushed a changeset. On another server I pulled but don't see it. It looks that server where I pushed is on different branch compared with another server. My confusion is that `hg tip` show my changes but actually repository was not changed. How could I align both servers?

Server where I push:

```
$ hg sum
parent: 248:5d07ada6be64 tip
 Add Pass/Fail flag
branch: default
commit: 3 unknown (clean)
update: 13 new changesets, 6 branch heads (merge)
```

Server where I pull:

```
$ hg tip
changeset:   248:5d07ada6be64
tag:         tip
parent:      241:c2d0cdc625a8
user:        vhabhsvoldme
date:        Mon Dec 07 11:27:24 2020 -0500
summary:     Add Pass/Fail flag
```

I run `hg update` but I see that file was not updated.

If I delete my repository where I pull and clone it from the server where I pushed ... it worked correct but when I pull it actually did not update.

Could you advice how to align my servers?

Thanks

Comment: If you are working on 2 different branches you will not see any updates to your working directory. You may need to merge from the other branch.

Comment: Well I am not positive that my issue is consistent. On another server I deleted repository, cloned it again. Than I push and pull and did not have any issue. I am planning to do the same on the server where I have the issue. My point: for some reason it was 'a mess' on the server and in case it's a 'real' issue I will hit it soon again, Thanks

Comment: If you do have the problem again, update the question with more detail if you can. One thing I was not sure of was what you meant by "server"

Comment: Sure I will update it in case I hit it again. By "server" I meant that on repository I use is located on Server where we do development and usually push new changes. Second time I mentioned "server" I actually meant just my laptop where I pull those changes and analyze it if needed. Sorry for confusion